# Invalid zip file reading from a Stream in C#

Tags: c#

I have the following code:

```
private static byte[] ConverterStringToByte(Stream body)
{

    string fileName = "data_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddhhmmss") + ".zip";
    // Take out the bytes from the memory stream and safely close the stream
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        body.CopyTo(ms);
        using (var zipArchive = new ZipArchive(ms, ZipArchiveMode.Create, false))
        {
            var zipEntry = zipArchive.CreateEntry(fileName, CompressionLevel.Optimal);
            using (BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(zipEntry.Open()))
            {
                ms.Position = 0;
                writer.Write(ms.ToArray());
            }
        }
            
        return ms.ToArray();
    }
}
```

I am downloading the file successfully, however I'm getting

> invalid file

when trying to open

Comment: You are writing `ms` to itself. And overwrite it when creating the Archive. Use 2 MemoryStreems.

Comment: What are you trying to do? It looks like you're accepting a stream (in zip format), then you're trying to adding a zip file to itself? The name `ConverterStringToByte` doesn't seem to describe what it's doing.

Comment: Hard to tell for sure, but I'm guessing you want to return the zip file itself. In that case you should replace `return ms.ToArray();` with `return System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(fileName);` Otherwise you are just saving the zip file locally and returning the original, uncompressed data stream to the caller.

Comment: True, trying to return the zip file.
Tried this not working


      private static byte[] ConverterStringToByte(Stream body)
        {

            using var ms = new MemoryStream();
            body.CopyTo(ms);
             return System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(body);

        }

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be something like this. Not sure about `fileName` though, because it's the name of the file being put into archive, so I don't think it should have *.zip extension. Unless you are creating a zip of zips.

```cs
static byte[] ConverterStringToByte(Stream body)
{
    string fileName = @"data_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddhhmmss") + ".zip";

    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (var zipArchive = new ZipArchive(ms, ZipArchiveMode.Create, false))
        {
            var zipEntry = zipArchive.CreateEntry(fileName, CompressionLevel.Optimal);
            using (var destStream = zipEntry.Open())
            {
                body.CopyTo(destStream);
            }
        }

        return ms.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Comment: //so i'm getting a stream (zip file format) response from another endpoint and want to use it:


        var fileName = String.Concat(name, "_", Id, "_", details.Id, ".zip");
        form.Add(fileContent, "files", fileName);

           //However, it was not working.I now resorted to converting to btyeArray Content to read the stream and pass correctly, reason for writing


                 //"ConverterStringToByte" method and calling it as below:

                    var fileContent = new ByteArrayContent(ConverterStringToByte(file));

Comment: It's not clear what exactly is the problem. What error do you get? Also could you please share the code of controller (or whatever is handling the request and sending the response). You can also try to send some existing file in the reponse and first troubleshoot the response sending part.

Comment: private static byte[] ConverterStringToByte(Stream body)
        {

            using var ms = new MemoryStream();
            body.CopyTo(ms);
            return System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(body);

        }

Comment: so the issue is i'm passing a stream i get from another endpoint on formData to another endpoint.

Comment: Are you returning is like this? `return File(ConverterStringToByte(stream), "application/zip", "Images.zip");`

Comment: with this method, "ConverterStringToByte" i'm able to convert the stream first to byte before sending to the second endpoint formData

However, i am getting "Invalid file" when trying to open the downloaded file on my PC.

Comment: Below is how i'm using the "ConvertStringToByte".

  var file = await _dms.MultipleAttachmentDownloadAsync(request);
  var fileName = String.Concat(name, "_", Id, "_", details.Id, ".zip");
   var fileContent = new ByteArrayContent(ConverterStringToByte(file));
 form.Add(fileContent, "files", fileName);

Comment: What if instead of ConverterStringToByte() you create and populate a byte[] array with some test data? Will you be able to download the file and will it contain correct data?